# Performance em Queryset CBV

Tags: django, django-generic-views

```
# models.py
class Book(TimeStampedModel):
    name = models.CharField(_('nome'), max_length=50)
    authors = models.ManyToManyField('Author', verbose_name='autores')
    price = models.DecimalField(_(u'preço'), max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)

# views.py
class BookList(ListView):
    template_name = 'core/book_list.html'
    model = Book

    def get_queryset(self):
        ''' use prefetch_related for m2m performance '''
        b = Book.objects.prefetch_related('authors').all()
        return b
```

Vocês acham que precisa mesmo de `prefetch_related` para melhorar a performance da queryset? Ou não precisa? O CBV do Django já faz isso automaticamente?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para analisar a *performance* você pode instalar o `django-debug-toolbar`:

```
pip install django-debug-toolbar
```

Com ele você pode analisar quantas *queries* são feitas em uma consulta.
Mas o `prefetch_related` otimiza sim suas consultas.